# Confusion about return type of a function when it is a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value

I wrote the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int * myFunction()
{
    int * p = new int(5);
    return p;
}
 
int main()
{
    int * q = myFunction();
    cout << "*q=" << *q;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I purposely wrote the above code to receive an error. The mistake I made is that I stated the return type of function `myFunction()` as `const int *` but when I called `myFunction()` in `main()`, the pointer variable `q` was not declared `const`. The return type of `myFunction()` must match exactly to the type of variable which is going to receive its return value (am I correct here? This is what I have understood).

So, I fixed the error by correcting line 11 as `const int * q = myFunction();`. Now the type of the (pointer)variable `q`, which is `const int *`, matched exactly to the return type of `myFunction()` and the code compiled without error, producing output as `*q=5` (is my understanding up to this point correct?).

Then, I wrote the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int * const myFunction()
{
    int * p = new int(5);
    cout << "p: " << p;
    return p;
}
 
int main()
{
    int a;
    const int * q = myFunction();
    cout << "\nq=" << q;
    cout << "\n*q=" << *q;
    delete q;
    q = &a;
    cout << "\nq: " << q;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting an error here, too. Because now the return type of `myFunction()` is `const int * const` but the (pointer)variable `q` had type `const int *`. `q` was not declared as a constant pointer. But the program compiled and I got output as follows:

```
p: 0x36cb8
q=0x36cb8
*q=5
q: 0x61ff08
```

I am confused why the second code compiles and runs. What I thought is whoever is going to receive the return value from `myFunction()` should always take care of it (i.e. it cannot be allowed to take a different memory address), but the pointer variable `q` took a different memory location.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: The caller assumes ownership of the pointer, so it can decide about the constness of the pointer itself.

Comment: The second `const` in the function declaration is irrelevant, because the function doesn't have any control over the caller's variables, only the data that it returns.

Comment: Remember that the pointer is just another variable that just happens to hold an address. `const` or not, it can be copied to a non-`const` variable, and that's exactly what happened here. This is similar to `const int x = 10; int y = x; y = 42;`

Comment: You might want to enable warnings for your compiler.  For me, the `-Wignored-qualifiers` warning pointed out that the second const has no effect.

Comment: @Eljay I am using gcc (version 6.3.0). I just google how to get warnings and found keyword ```-Wall``` should be used. But I still didn't receive any warning. Is there any other way to enable warnings?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. It was helpful.

Comment: @Jesper The  `const` in the bit you quoted is relevant, since it affects `int`.  it means the caller of the function can’t change theepointed-to value.  The second `const` latersin the question doesn’t do anything.

Comment: @user4581301 I have a small doubt. When I mention the return type of a function, then is it stating the type of variable I am returning or is it stating the type of variable that going to receive the value? To be more clear, in second code, the return type ```const int * const``` is talking about pointer variable p(which is returned) or is it talking about the one who is going to receive it(i.e. q) ?

Comment: The type the function are returning. There is no way for the function to know what the caller will do, if anything, with the returned value, and can only enforce so much. If the receiver does accept the returned value, it's up to the receiver to use it in a manner that can be supported by the returned type.

Comment: GCC's `-Wall` enables some warnings, but not all warnings.  (The flag is bit misnamed, it seems to me.)  Last time I checked, GCC does not have a way to enable **all** warnings with a single flag, but that was quite a while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The return type of myFunction must match exactly to the type of variable which is going the receive it's return value. (Am I correct here? This is what I have understood.)

No, the return type must not match exactly to the type of the variable. But it must be possible to implicitly convert the return type to the type of the variable.
For example something like this will compile:

```
int someInt = getMeAFloat();
```

If `getMeAFloat` returns a `float`, this will compile because a `float` can be implicitly converted to an `int`. (Note that this gives you a warning and is bad because you lose the extra information of the `float`, but I am just trying to bring my point across)

Your first example does not compile because normally a `const int*` can not be converted to a `int*`.

As pointed out by user4581301 the second `const` in your second example does not matter, because only the value of the pointer, which is returned, gets assigned to the pointer in the main function. The second `const` makes the pointer itself constant, which has no effect on the value.
That means that `const int * const myFunction()` is equal to `const int * myFunction()`

Comment: [Documentation on Implicit Conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) Note that this is different from a cast because a cast is an explicit conversion

Comment: Thanks. I have one small doubt. In the first code, inside the body of ```myFunction``` , we set the type of (pointer)variable ```p``` as ```int *``` but while returning it, we changed it to ```const int *```.  This is bit confusing to me. How are we allowed to change the type of particular variable in the function header? I tried to do the same inside the body of function i.e. I wrote the following lines ``` int * p=new int(5); const int * p;``` . But I received error. I tried to change the type from ```int *``` to ```const int *``` in the body itself, but why is that receiving error?

Comment: @Believer see my other comment to this same question on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the 2nd code, `q` is a `const int *` - a non-const "pointer to a `const int`".  Since `q` itself is not `const`, it can be re-assigned to point at a new address.

The compiler allows `q = &a;` because an `int*` (ie, what `&a` returns since `a` is an `int`) can be assigned to a `const int*`.  In other words, a "pointer to non-const data" can be assigned to a "pointer to const data", effectively making read-only access to otherwise-writable data.

The reverse is not true - a "pointer to const data" cannot be assigned to a "pointer to non-const data", as that would allow writable access to read-only data - which is why the 1st code fails to compile.

Comment: Thanks. I have one small doubt. In the first code, inside the body of ```myFunction``` , we set the type of (pointer)variable ```p``` as ```int *``` but while returning it, we changed it to ```const int *```.  This is bit confusing to me. How are we allowed to change the type of particular variable in the function header? I tried to do the same inside the body of function i.e. I wrote the following lines ``` int * p=new int(5); const int * p;``` . But I received error. I tried to change the type from ```int *``` to ```const int *``` in the body itself, but why is that receiving error?

Comment: @Believer "*How are we allowed to change the type of particular variable in the function header?*" - I covered that in my answer. `int*` is implicitly convertible to `const int*`, eg: `int a; const int *q = &a;` "*I tried to do the same inside the body of function i.e. I wrote the following lines `int * p=new int(5); const int * p;` . But I received error.*" - you are declaring two variables named `p` in the same scope, you can't do that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Did you miss * between int and a while giving example of how ```int *```  is implicitly convertible to ```const int *```. i.e. is it ```int *a; const int *q = &a; ```

Comment: @Believer no, I didn't. `&a` is `int*` when `a` is `int`, and is `int**` when `a` is `int*`, etc